# IF, THEN Google Sheets formula help

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm having trouble figuring out the right formula for an if, then scenario in Google Sheets. I have two tabs of separate spreadsheets open in one Google Sheet. I need the second tab (**Cost Analysis**) to reference the first tab **(Responses**). In **Responses** I have 3 columns that say either *Mimaki* or *Roland* and 3 more columns with numerical values. In **Cost Analysis**, I need to create the following formula:

If cells A2, B2, C2 in **Responses** say *Mimaki*, then multiply the numbers in cells D2, E2, F2 in **Responses** by 10. If column A2, B2, C2 in **Responses** says *Roland*, then multiply the numbers in D, E, F, in Responses by 20.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. *"If cells A2, B2, C2 in Responses say Mimaki, then..."* Not quite sure what you need. Do all cells have the same values, or...?? Your Data is insufficient. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to do this for more rows than just row 2 (i.e., that you will want to do this for rows 2 and downward). If that is correct, make sure you have three empty columns side by side in the 'Cost Analysis' sheet and then try this formula in the upper leftmost corner of that three-column range:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER(IFS(Responses!A2:C="Mimaki",10,Responses!A2:C="Roland",20,TRUE,1/0)*Responses!D2:F,Responses!A2:A&Responses!B2:B&Responses!C2:C<>"")))`

If you actually do want this to process *only* row 2, use this version:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR((IFS(Responses!A2:C2="Mimaki",10,Responses!A2:C2="Roland",20,TRUE,1/0)*Responses!D2:F2)))`

How It Works:

`IFERROR` just catches any instances where you might have a name cell that is blank, in which case a blank result will show rather than an error.

The IFS setup should be clear up to the `TRUE` pair. `TRUE` just means "anything not already covered earlier." In this case, if an A:C cell is blank or contains anything other than "Mimaki" or "Roland," the result will be 1/0. And since anything divided by 0 is a #DIV0 error, `IFERROR` will kick in and leave that cell blank in the results.

In the first (array) version, I used `FILTER(... Responses!A2:A&Responses!B2:B&Responses!C2:C<>"")` around everything to filter in only rows from Responses!A2:C that are not entirely blank. If left out, you would need to place the formula only in row 1 or 2 of the 'Cost Analysis' sheet, or you'd throw an error (because every row of Responses!A2:C would be processed entirely, whether blank or not.) That part isn't necessary if you're only processing one row.